# Which of these connections are incorrect and why?

Tags: phase

Is there a difference in these connections and is there anything wrong on any connection? I am new to phase and neutral wiring. Kindly help me.
[image]

Comment: Use the CircuitLab schematic button on the question's editor toolbar to draw a schematic of the cartoons and it should become obvious pretty quickly. You can add that into your question and we can check your understanding.

Comment: ask yourself this `is the lamp socket hot when the switch is turned off?`

Comment: That drawing is truly atrocious. Worse yet: the P and N, *and* the colors, hint at positive and negative and this could be a question about a low voltage circuit, where circuits 1 and 2 are equivalent. If P and N mean phase and neutral, circuits 1 and 2 are not equivalent, since we want to switch phase and not neutral for electrical safety reasons. *Sites that proclaim "Master", "Geek", "Expert" in their names are more often than not the exact opposite*.

Comment: @Alex I think this question could be salvageable if you took the effort to redraw the picture so that it's not visually offensive, and clarify what P and N mean. The colors of the conductors are not very necessary, clear labels suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting colour codes aside*.

Option 2 is correct.

Option 1 will work, but is against regulations in the US, the UK and likely many other places. The problem is that the load will still be "live", even when turned off. This is considered undesirable from a safety perspective.

Option 3 will leave the light on when the switch is open and cause a short circuit when the switch is closed.

* Before doing any work you should find out what the colour codes are where you live (and whether people actually follow them). The colour codes in your image are wrong for the USA and archaic for the UK, but I believe there are some places where they are still correct.

Answer (score 2):

1. Technically works electrically. But will not meet national code.
2. Technically works electrically and does meet code (The neutral conductor needs to be white)
3. Does not work properly - The light will be on when the switch is off. And the circuit shorts out when the switch is turned on.

The salient point is you typically want to leave the neutral connected to the load and switch the phase(s).